# Change duplicate elements to 0, others to 1 in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I want to compare each element of an array with others. If two elements are equal then one should be changed to 1, the other to 0.

What did I do wrong?

```
package org.kodejava.example.io;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Root {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr()));
    }

    public static int[] arr() {
        int[] arc ={1,2,5,76,8,0,6,5,1,4,8,4,6,};

        for (int i=0;i<13;i++){
            for (int j=1;j<13;j++){

                if (arc[i] == arc[j] ) {

                    arc[i]=1;
                    arc[j]=0;

                }
                else { 
                    arc[i]=1;
                }
            }
        }

        return arc;
    }

}
```

In this example, I would like to get a line like that: `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1...]`

Howewer, my attempt finished with `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Thanks in advance!

Another example, if we have a sequence `[1,1,4,6]` then the final result should be `[1,0,1,1]`. So if the element is met more than once only one must be equal to 1 and the others to 0.

Comment: "doesn't work properly" is rather useless. Tell us how it's not working.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve and why the result doesn't meet your expectations?

Comment: @Hazaart I've edited my question. I wouild compare each of element in array with others the if there two equals elements at least or more - > only one of the has become equal 1, other = 0

Comment: you've chosen weird task. Let's sort this array :)

Comment: @houman001 actually this question is not duplicate since it is not about how to print content of array but more about why this content is not correct (whatever OP means).

Comment: You might have been copying/pasting from the other one, as I could read it as: How to deal with arrays in JAVA?
there! I'm a novice in Java programming. I couldn't understand in the following case why my code doesn't work properly: System.out.print(arr()); Instead of all of results I got this: '[D@60e1e567' ...

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind the question? I.e. what rules  determine when should you get `1` and when `0` ?

Comment: @houman001  they are different questions

Comment: @user000001 Look at my comment above, please

Comment: @user000001 There are different NOW, not when I read it!

Comment: I'm happy to take back my -1, just edit the question as I'm not allowed to unless you edit the question.

Comment: @user000001 but what about a question? do you now why it's not working?

Comment: This question cannot be answered unless you explain what the computational process is supposed to be.  Why should the result be that?  What does it mean?

Comment: @Stephen C I wouild compare each of element in array with others the if there two equals elements at least or more - > only one of the has become equal 1, other = 0

Comment: I read it as `1` if the element is dublicate `0` otherwise. But then the second element should be `0`. Could you clarify?

Comment: @user000001 for example, if we have a sequence [1,1,4,6] then the final result should be [1,0,1,1] so if the element is meet more than once only one must be equal 1

Answer (score 5):

Maybe here's the function that you want:

```
public static int[] arr() {
    int[] arc ={1,2,5,76,8,0,6,5,1,4,8,4,6};

    for (int i=0;i<arc.length;i++){
        for (int j=i+1;j<arc.length;j++){

            if (arc[i] == arc[j] && arc[i] != 0) {
                arc[i]=1;
                arc[j]=0;
            }
        }

        if(arc[i] != 0) {
            arc[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    return arc;
}
```

Note `arc.length` and `arc[i] != 0` check and the inner loop going from `i+1`.

**UPDATE**

I rewrote my function so that it satisfies now the condition that first 0 should be 1 in the end. It gets the array now as parameter. There's some optimization as inner loop will not run in case of the element on the corresponding index is 0 already.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Root {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arc = {1,2,5,76,8,0,6,5,1,4,8,4,6};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr(arc)));
    }

    public static int[] arr(int[] arc) {
        int indexOfTheFirstZero = -1;

        // find the first 0 and store its index
        for (int i=0;i<arc.length;i++){
            if(arc[i] == 0) {
                indexOfTheFirstZero = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        // main loop
        for (int i=0;i<arc.length;i++){

            // need work only if item is not 0
            if(arc[i] != 0) {

                for (int j=i+1;j<arc.length;j++){
                    if (arc[i] == arc[j]) {
                        arc[j] = 0;
                    }
                }

                arc[i]=1;
            }
        }

        // change first 0 (if it exists) to 1
        if(indexOfTheFirstZero != -1) {
            arc[indexOfTheFirstZero] = 1;
        }

        return arc;
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry, You know, I can't do it. I got too bad reputation because of this question ;(

Comment: This answer is not correct. The sixth element should be `1`not `0`.

Comment: You are right. Works under condition that array doesn't contain zero. Or do it with -1 not zero then change -1s to 0s.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I updated my answer so that my function now satisfies the condition that first 0 should be 1 in the end. There's also some optimization.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int[] arr() {
    int[] arc = {1, 1, 4, 6};
    int[] result = new int[arc.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arc.length; i++) { // Changed 13 to arc.length
        result[i] = 1; // Suppose not duplicate until proven wrong
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { // first element is 0, only need to check up to current elememt
            if (arc[i] == arc[j]) {
                result[i] = 0; // Found a duplicate. Element i should be zero   
//             arc[j]=0; No need to change arc[j]. 
                break; // No need to check the rest of the array
//         } else {  // The else is now unnecessary

            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```